# how can I List files in order

Tags: command-line, files, scripts, ls, cat

I had an 18GB file I needed to download on a less than great Internet connection. Torrenting  wasn't an option. So I busted up the file into 100 segments, and eventually, all of it downloaded. Now I need to put the files back together, using a program which is like cat.

So I need to list the files, in counting order, and concatenate them.
The FileNames go something like SomeFile1.dcd, SomeFile2.dcd, SomeFile3.dcd SomeFile10.dcd,  ... SomeFile100.dcd

for the concatenation to work properly, I need to list the files in normal numerical order, otherwise the frames will be all screwy.

how can I list the files in normal numerical  1,2,3,4.... type order?

Comment: It would have been easier to use `wget` (`man wget`) with the `--continue` option, in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `bash` brace expansion :

```
cat SomeFile{1..100}.dcd >final_file
```

You can have a check at first to see which files it is being expanded to by :

```
echo SomeFile{1..100}.dcd
```

Here `{1..100}` will be expanded to `1,2,3....100`.

**Example :**

```
$ echo SomeFile{1..5}.dcd
SomeFile1.dcd SomeFile2.dcd SomeFile3.dcd SomeFile4.dcd SomeFile5.dcd
```

Comment: Short, precise, perfect. :) +1

Comment: For future reference, the `split` command creates files whose names are lexically ordered in the first place. Then, `cat SomeFile*.dcd` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

`perl` can also use the expansion syntax in loops:

```
perl -e 'print "SomeFile$_.dcd " for 1..100' > foo.txt
```

Comment: Nice, but `find` and `sort` also =)

Answer (score 1):

using `find` and `sort`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.dcd" | sort -V
```

Comment: `sort -V` is a clever choice, and also +1 to use the existing files.

Answer (score 0):

Globbing patterns will expand to the *ordered* list of files (and directories) matching the globbing pattern;

If you have only those files in your current working directory, simply:

```
cat * > out
```

Or if there are no other files / directories that start with "SomeFile":

```
cat SomeFile* > out
```

Or if there are no other files / directories that end with ".dcd":

```
cat *.dcd > out
```

Also, in `zsh`, you may include only regular files using the `*(.)` globbing pattern:

```
cat *(.) > out
cat SomeFile*(.) > out
cat *(.).dcd > out
```